# How to preinstall addin on Office Online server?

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins

Is there any way to preinstall an addin onto an on-premise Office Online server such that when a user starts Word online, the addin will already be there?

I've read the documentation on centralized deployment through Office 365, but it mentions Office Online server is not supported.

Comment: This isn't really a programming questions, it is IT administration. I would suggest posting this on [serverFault [(https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: Ah, good point. I had seen some Office Online server questions on Stack Overflow so I posted here, but serverfault is better. I'll post there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with current functionality.